# Use two forms to do it on winform

Tags: winforms

Use 2 forms to do this on winform.
opacity set first form 40%
Call the second form in the first form as follows
Form2 f2 = new Form2 ();

```
        f2.Owner = this;
        
        f2.Show ();
```

Comment: To do what, exactly? Are you trying to explain how to show a translucent Form with *solid* child Controls? -- To set the owner, you should do `f2.Show(this);`

Comment: As Jimi said, this question needs clarification of what exactly you need to do, I can't ssem to find a solution to this as there is 1 line of text and 2 lines of code present here.
Please put more detail into your question and maybe then someone can help you.